# Как подключиться к каналу по Websocket?

Tags: c#, laravel, websocket, xamarin

Я делаю простое чат приложение на Xamarin (клиент) и Laravel (сервер)
Настроил вебсокеты на сервере с помощью библиотеки **laravel websockets** и **pusher**

Вот мой event NewMessage

```
 class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('chat-room');
    }

    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return [
            "message" => $this->message
        ];
    }
}
```

Я зарегистрировал канал chat-room

```
Broadcast::channel('chat-room', function ($message) {
  return true;
});
```

Я успешно могу подключиться со своего клиента по сокетам, используя библиотеку WebSocketSharp (C#)
Однако, мне приходит в метод onMessage только это

```
data: "{"socket_id":"249965922.74383293","activity_timeout":30}"
```

Уведомляя меня о том , что я подключился к серверу, а мне надо дальше подлюкчится к chat-room, но в документации к библиотеке не описано как это делать. Возможно ли это ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static  void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Con1();
        }

        private static async Task Con1()
        {
            using (WebSocketSharp.WebSocket web = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.105:6001/app/ABCDEFG"))
            {
                web.OnMessage += WsOnMEssage;
                web.Connect();
                web.Ping();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static void WsOnMEssage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так после установки соединения вы не давали команды на подписку на нужный вам канал. Заодно прочитайте про настройки [Broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816655/laravel-websockets-subscribing-to-private-channels-does-not-work), которые могут вам мешать.

Comment: Дело в том, что в C# нет актуальной бибилотеки (или я недосаточно искал), которая позволяет пописываться на каналы, как в том же Laravel Echo (js). / могу подключаться только по ссылкам: ws:://host:posrt

Comment: Сейчас думаю вместе laravel-websockets использовать Ratchet в проекте. Возможно это решит мою проблему. Что скажете?

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть что происходит при вызове метода subscribe в [документации](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/public-channels/#subscribe)

Comment: Это документация Pusher. Я не использую данный сервис и его библиотеки, так как их нет для C# и Xamarin официально